# How to add calculations on a pandas groupby table?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

I've created a table using pandas.groupby, but want to add a column that does a calculation on the columns in the groupby output.  Here is my code (I'm using Python 2) and result:

```
DMM_pivot = df.query('rpc_flag != "IB RPC"').groupby(['rpc_flag', 'DMM_type'])
DMM_pivot = DMM_pivot['number_accounts'].sum().unstack('rpc_flag').fillna(0)
DMM_pivot = DMM_pivot.apply(lambda x: x / x.sum()).round(2)  # Show percentage of total
print DMM_pivot

rpc_flag  No RPC  OB RPC
DMM_type                
Bad         0.34    0.25
Good        0.66    0.75
```

I want to add a column that shows percentage difference accross the columns: (OB RPC value / No RPC value - 1) and expect these results:

```
rpc_flag  No RPC  OB RPC   Change
DMM_type                
Bad         0.34    0.25    -0.26
Good        0.66    0.75     0.14
```

Comment: whats wrong with `df['OB RPC'].div(df['No RPC']) - 1` ?

Comment: @Datanovice 'OB RPC' is a value within `df['rpc_flag']`, not a column in the dataframe.  I think this would work if I wanted to add a new column to the dataframe or calculate on the dataframe rows, but not as a new column in the groupby output.  NOTE: speculation because I'm very much a beginner here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apply.

```
DMM_pivot["Change"] = DMM_pivot.apply(lambda x: x["OB RPC"]/x["No RPC"] -1, axis=1)
```

Comment: @HokieSpider happy to hear. Upvoting/accepting would be appreciated.

Comment: It says I can accept in 4 minutes and I need 5 more reputation points to upvote.  I'll come back and do both once I can.